# Facing issue while calling Hibernate with Spring

Tags: spring

> I am just trying to use Hibernate using Spring framework. Lets say
>   have created a DAO classes and xml files below.

```
package org.java.dao;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.java.spring.dataModel.Circle;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
@Repository
public class HibernateDao {
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;


    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }


    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }


    public int getCircleCount(){

        String hql="Select count(*) from circle";
        Query query=getSessionFactory().openSession().createQuery(hql);
     return ((Long)query.uniqueResult()).intValue();

    }

}

package org.java.Main;

import org.java.dao.HibernateDao;
import org.java.spring.dataModel.Circle;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class HibernateDemo {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx= new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
        HibernateDao dao=ctx.getBean("hibernateDao",HibernateDao.class);
        System.out.println("Circle is:"+dao.getCircleCount());


    }

}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.java.dao" />

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"></property>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hibernatedb"></property>
        <property name="username" value="postgres"></property>
        <property name="password" value="****"></property>
        <!--
            <property name="initialSize" value="2"></property> <property
            name="maxActive" value="5"></property>
        -->
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.java.dao" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
            </props>
        </property>

    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>


    </beans>
```

> But I am getting this error while running the application.
>
> 15 Feb, 2014 12:18:35 PM
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext
>   prepareRefresh INFO: Refreshing
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@145d068:
>   startup date [Sat Feb 15 12:18:35 IST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
>   15 Feb, 2014 12:18:35 PM
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader
>   loadBeanDefinitions INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path
>   resource [spring.xml] 15 Feb, 2014 12:18:36 PM
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory
>   preInstantiateSingletons INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@dc57db:
>   defining beans
>   [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,hibernateDao,dataSource,sessionFactory,transactionManager,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor];
>   root of factory hierarchy 15 Feb, 2014 12:18:36 PM
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource
>   setDriverClassName INFO: Loaded JDBC driver: org.postgresql.Driver 15
>   Feb, 2014 12:18:36 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version
>    INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations
>   {4.0.1.Final} 15 Feb, 2014 12:18:36 PM org.hibernate.Version
>   logVersion INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.1.12.Final} 15 Feb, 2014
>   12:18:36 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment  INFO: HHH000206:
>   hibernate.properties not found 15 Feb, 2014 12:18:36 PM
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider INFO: HHH000021:
>   Bytecode provider name : javassist 15 Feb, 2014 12:18:37 PM
>   org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect  INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect:
>   org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect 15 Feb, 2014 12:18:37 PM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder
>   useContextualLobCreation INFO: HHH000423: Disabling contextual LOB
>   creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [3] less than 4 15 Feb,
>   2014 12:18:37 PM
>   org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator
>   initiateService INFO: HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy
>   (direct JDBC transactions) 15 Feb, 2014 12:18:37 PM
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory  INFO:
>   HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory 15 Feb, 2014 12:18:37 PM
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager
>   afterPropertiesSet INFO: Using DataSource
>   [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource@aea710]
>   of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager Exception
>   in thread "main" org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException:
>   circle is not mapped [Select count(*) from circle]    at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:180)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:110)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:93)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:324)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3291)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3180)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:706)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:562)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:299)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:247)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:248)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:183)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:105)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:168)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:221)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:199)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1735)
>     at org.java.dao.HibernateDao.getCircleCount(HibernateDao.java:29)   at
>   org.java.Main.HibernateDemo.main(HibernateDemo.java:16)

Answer (score 1):

You are writing an HQL query rather than a SQL query. The syntax is similar, but you use mapped types in your HQL queries. In this case, since the mapped type is apparently `Circle`, try the following:

`select count(c) from Circle c`

As the exception indicates, `circle` isn't a mapped type, which makes sense.

Comment: You get the same exception? It would be pretty weird to get a `circle is not mapped` message from a query without `circle` in it.

Answer (score 0):

Packagestoscan properties should point to entities

Here., org.java.spring.dataModel

Comment: Here is my Circle which is just a Pojo.public class Circle {

 public int getId() {
  return id;
 }
 public void setId(int id) {
  this.id = id;
 }
 public String getName() {
  return name;
 }
 public void setName(String name) {
  this.name = name;
 }
 private int id;
 private String name;
 
 public Circle(int circleId,String circleName){
  setId(id);
  setName(circleName); 
 }
 public Circle() {
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
 }
}

Comment: You are right but after resolving this: I get this error now.Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory org.java.dao.HibernateDao.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [spring.xml]:

Comment: Yeah, it really sounds like you have [99 Problems](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WwoM5fLITfk&feature=kp).

Answer (score 0):

My answer might be long overdue, but for future refference, this might work:

We'll have to change a couple of things, here we go :

First:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
    <property name="username" value="postgres"></property>
    <property name="password" value="****"></property>
```

And in the sessionFactory :

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.java.dao" />

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

This will work without this:

```
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Also, cosnsider that, you have mapped types in your HQL queries. Therefore do:

```
select count(c) from Circle c
```